# Objective-C cocoa application overwrite a JSON file

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa, overwrite

How to overwrite a json file using values of other json file? 
I'm using 2 json files for data storage of the configuration of the app, one is the default values for the app, and the other is the custom configuration values given by the user, it will always run retrieving the data from the custom file, so in the case that the user wants to restore the original configuration, it takes the values of the default file and overwrite the custom file, thats the logic, but I am still trying to figure out how to overwrite the files.

Here is what I was trying to do in the code, but still isn't writing anything:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"custom" ofType:@"json"];
    // Retrieve local JSON file called custom.json
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSError *error = nil; // This so that we can access the error if something goes wrong
    NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];
    // Load the file into an NSData object called JSONData

    NSDictionary *lista = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:0 error:nil];

    NSNumber * test = [lista objectForKey:@"tempoTrabalho1"];
    NSInteger teste = [test integerValue];

    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)teste);

    //file to copy from
    NSString *json = [ [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"example" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:json options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    //write file to device
    [jsonData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}

@end
```

I want to overwrite the custom.json with the example.json:

example.json:

```
{
    "tempoTrabalho1": 25,
    "tempoTrabalho2": 25,
    "tempoTrabalho3": 25,
    "tempoTrabalho4": 25,
    "tempoDescanso1": 5,
    "tempoDescanso2": 5,
    "tempoDescanso3": 5,
    "tempoDescanso4": 20
}
```

custom.json:

```
{
    "tempoTrabalho1": 30,
    "tempoTrabalho2": 30,
    "tempoTrabalho3": 30,
    "tempoTrabalho4": 30,
    "tempoDescanso1": 10,
    "tempoDescanso2": 10,
    "tempoDescanso3": 10,
    "tempoDescanso4": 30
}
```

Comment: I dont believe you are allowed to overwrite resources. Doesnt that invalidate the signature?

Comment: isn't possible to write a json? because I can read and get the values of the json file, but I need to write them somewhere, and i can't find how to do that

Comment: @JulianIgnacio Your code looks fine; you are not writing to the app bundle, so should work fine.  You probably want to write to the Application Support folder instead of Documents, however, so the user cannot see the file.

Comment: Log the file paths you're using.

Comment: thanks for the answers people, I edited and added the json files, I want to overwrite one with the other.

Comment: @JulianIgnacio So the question is not about overwriting files at all; it's about modifying the data between reading and writing :@

Comment: @trojanfoe, sorry for my english if I put it the wrong way, but I want to do that, write just the custom file with the user customization, and in the case to restore default, use the values of my default json(in this case example.json) to overwrite the custom file.

Answer (score 1):

The [`[NSData writeToFile:atomically:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:atomically:) method will overwrite by default (you'd have to use the version of the method that accepts options and specify `NSDataWritingWithoutOverwriting` in order to **not** overwrite).